# Java Array storing objects with multiple fields

Tags: java

I have public class Vehicle with two subclasses `Car` and `Truck` that each extend `Vehicle`.  The constructor for each class is the same with 3 fields, color, brand and gas mileage.

I've declared an array

```
Vehicle [] vehArray = new Vehicle[6];
```

that will store 6 different vehicles.  I know a call

```
Car car1 = new Car("Red", "Ford", 15);
```

will instantiate `car1` with an object of type `Car`.

How would I store `car1` in `vehArray[0]`?

Comment: you can just do `vehArray[0] = car1` .....

Comment: Voted to be closed as being of very low quality. Seriously, get some minimum background research before asking question.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a valid question.

Comment: I m not the downvoter, but they obviously try to say that you almost had a solution for this question. Everything you were missing is an '=' sign between the car1 and the vehArray=)

Comment: Wasting much time of others for something that can be tried in a jiffy...

Answer (score 3):

Try doing something like this:

```
vehArray[0] = car1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do Car vehArray[0] =new Car("Red", "Ford", 15);?

Comment: yeah, I think it should also work, just try it if you are not sure. The compiler will complain if it doesn't work=)

Comment: Someone tries to edit a useless cast into this statement - I've just removed it.

Comment: Not sure if cast is really needed

Comment: You better be sure that it is not needed.

Comment: Thats what I thought while answering, subclasses should be known=)

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way is:

```
vehArray [0] = new Car("Red", "Ford", 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even

```
Vehicle[] vehArray = new Vehicle[]{new Car("Red", "Ford", 15), new Truck("Silver", "Mercedes", 2)};
```

Answer (score 0):

As below;

1) Test.java;

---

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Array Initialization with null Vehicle placeholders
        Vehicle[] vehicleArray = new Vehicle[6];

        //Car class object instances are assiged
        for( int i = 0; i < vehicleArray.length; i++ )
            vehicleArray[i] = new Car("Red", "Ford", 15+i);

        for( int i = 0; i < vehicleArray.length; i++ )
            System.out.println
                (
                    i + 
                    " : " + vehicleArray[i].getColor() + 
                    " : " + vehicleArray[i].getBrand() + 
                    " : " + vehicleArray[i].getGasMilage()
                );
    }

}
```

2) Vehicle.java

---

```
public class Vehicle {

    private String color;
    private String brand;
    private int gasMilage;

    public Vehicle() {}

    //Constructor with fields
    public Vehicle(String color, String brand, int gasMilage) {
        this.color = color;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.gasMilage = gasMilage;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public int getGasMilage() {
        return gasMilage;
    }

    public void setGasMilage(int gasMilage) {
        this.gasMilage = gasMilage;
    }

}
```

3) Car.java

---

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    //no-arg constructor
    public Car() {
        super();
    }

    //field constructor
    public Car(String color, String brand, int gasMilage) {
        super(color, brand, gasMilage);
    }

}
```

4) Truck.java

---

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    //no-arg constructor
    public Truck() {
        super();
    }

    //field constructor
    public Truck(String color, String brand, int gasMilage) {
        super(color, brand, gasMilage);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest declaring all objects of subclasses first then it can be stored in vehicle like so :

```
Vehicle[] vehicleArray = {ob1,ob2,ob3,ob4,andSo_On};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean calling parent class constructor so you can use the fields in parent class?

Here's my take :)

*Vehicle.java*

```
public class Vehicle {

    String color, brand;
    int mileage;

    Vehicle(String c, String d, int e){
        color = c;
        brand = d;
        mileage = e;
    }
}
```

*Car.java*

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{
        
        Car(String c, String d, int e){
            super(c, d, e);
        }
        
}
```

*Test.java*

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Vehicle [] vehArray = new Vehicle[6];
        Car car1 = new Car("Red", "Ford", 15);
        Car car2 = new Car("Blue", "Audi", 17);
    
        vehArray[0] = car1;
        vehArray[1] = car2;
    
        System.out.println("Color: " + car1.color + "\nBrand: " + car1.brand + "\nMileage: " + car1.mileage + "\n");
        System.out.println("Color: " + car2.color + "\nBrand: " + car2.brand + "\nMileage: " + car2.mileage);
        
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            
            if(vehArray[i].color == "Blue")
            {
                System.out.println("\nCar is " + vehArray[i].brand);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I even did testing at the end just to make sure. You're welcome :D